# Eclipse Mylyn Task List looks broken after a while

Tags: eclipse, mantis, mylyn

When I open Eclipse the mylyn Task List looks OK. But after a while Icons, header background colors disappear and it looks corrupted. Even sometimes texts do disappear and it becomes unusable. When I close and open tasklist it looks OK again, but again it becomes broken after sometime. in error_log, all I can see is that it cannot find a gif file named /icons/full/elc16/gotoobj_tsk.gif.

I use mantis-mylyn connector. OS is Linux Mint 17.3. Running on Oracle Java 8 VM.

Looks good on initialization :

[image: on initializition]

Looks broken after a while :
[image: looks broken after a while]

Answer (score 0):

I made two things
1. Put old gif icons under .plugins/org.eclipse.jface. folder was not there so I created it. File not messages are gone, but issue persist.
2. Later I simply change desktop theme other than Mint-X dark. I saw that Issue was gone! I returned back to Mint-X dark again. Saw that issue was gone either in that theme. 
I don't know the exact source of problem and what solved it, but currently it looks OK.